# Problema de declaración de variables enlazando fotos con base de datos

Tags: php, html

Es una página ecommerce personal que estoy haciendo. Tengo una seccion que está el catalogo quiero mostrar cada producto con sus fotos en un slider, pero no estaria declarandome las variables y no tengo mucha experiencia en php y bases de datos.

```
<?php

require 'config/config.php';
require 'config/database.php';

$db = new database();
$con = $db->conectar();

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM productos WHERE activo=1");
$sql->execute();
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//
$id  = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1");
$sql->execute([$id]);

//

if ($sql->fetchColumn(0) > 0) {
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT nombre, descripcion, precio, categoria, color, marca, generacion, velocidad, modelo FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1");
    $sql->execute([$id]);
    $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $nombre = $row['nombre'];
    $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
    $precio = $row['precio'];
    $categoria = $row['categoria'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $marca = $row['marca'];
    $generacion = $row['generacion'];
    $velocidad = $row['velocidad'];
    $modelo = $row['modelo'];
    $id  = $row['nombre'];

    $dir_productos = 'img/productos/';
    $dir_images =  $dir_productos . $categoria . '/' . $marca . '/' . $modelo . '/';

    $dir = dir($dir_images);

    if ($categoria == "cpu") {
        while (($dir_images_cpu_leer = $dir->read()) != false) {
            if ($dir_images_cpu_leer == $generacion) {
                $dir_images = $dir_images . $generacion . '/';
            }
        }
    } elseif ($categoria == "ram") {
        while (($dir_images_ram_leer = $dir->read()) != false) {
            if ($dir_images_ram_leer == $velocidad) {
                $dir_images = $dir_images . $velocidad . '/' . $color . '/';
            }
        }
    }

    $dir_principal = $dir_productos . 'nophoto.png';
    if (!file_exists($dir_images)) {
        $dir_principal = 'img/productos/nophoto.png';
    } else {
        $dir_principal = $dir_images . 'principal.jpg';
    }


    //  ACA ENTRAN EN JUEGO LAS OTRAS IMAGENES PARA EL CAROUSEL

    if (file_exists($dir_images)) {

        $imagenes = array();
        $archivo = $dir->read();
        while ($archivo != false) {
            if ($archivo != 'principal.jpg') {
                $imagenes[] = $dir_images . $archivo . '/';
            }
        }
        $dir->close();
    }
}
```

[image: errores]

Este es el codigo donde llamo a las funciones para cada producto

```
<?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="card shadow-sm">
                            <div id="carouselImg" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="true">
                                <div class="carousel-inner">
                                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $dir_principal; ?>" class="d-block w-100">
                                    </div>
                                    <?php foreach ($imagenes as $img) { ?>
                                        <div class="carousel-item">
                                            <img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" class="d-block w-100">
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                               </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Tambien tengo una seccion de detalles para cada producto en la cual me toma la img principal. Las otras fotos de ese producto no me muestra, pero todavia no llegue a esa parte
Yo queria hacerlo de esta forma con tantas carpetas para tenerlo bien organizado en caso de tener muchos productos.

Comment: $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); devuelve  un array bidimencional o uno simple?

Comment: `array(1) { ["count(id)"]=> int(0) }` eso me devuelve

Comment: igualmente, tuve que sacar `$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` por encima del if, sino no me lo declara, es como que nunca entra al `if ($sql->fetchColumn(0) > 0)`

Comment: esa es la razon, nunca entra por que es 0 y no mayor a 0, `SELECT count(id) FROM productos WHERE id=? AND activo=1` devuelve 0, al no entrar no declara las variables que usas mas abajo

Comment: si le pongo >= 0, cuando entra me tira error de memoria  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 268435464 bytes) in D:\Programas\XAMPP\htdocs\daleeee\catalogo.php on line 69

Comment: la linea 69 es `$imagenes[] = $dir_images . $archivo . '/';`

Comment: usa la logica, si le pones que entre aun sin encontrar nada, es obvio que generaras errores al tratar de asignar nada a las variables, el primer sql era contar los producros, pero si saca 0 el segundo sql es ver los productos que claramente el primer sql te dijo que no hay

Comment: No necesitas hacer un SELECT COUNT primero, haz tu select normal, luego el Fetch y luego verifica los datos en sí mismos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica mejor lo que quieres hacer, pues no es normal que ejecutes **tres consultas** para una misma cosa cuando puedes ejecutar una sola consulta.

Comment: gracias, lo aplique, igualemente las lineas 4,5,7,8 las deje xq las necesito para el foreach dentro del html

Comment: no, ahora estoy editando la pregunta